# Showing or hiding part of the form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Good day,

I have table layout panel and I want to show different content in the same cell by clicking a button.

How can I accomplish it ?

I tried to dock panels with desired content in the same cell one on top another apply Hide() and Show() methods, but could not get the right result.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this through the designer, since it only allows a single control (or container control) in a cell.

You would have to swap it out:

```
Control c = tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(1, 1);
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(c);
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(userControl1, 1, 1);
```

Please note that Control c is not disposed of in my example.  You could still add it back in.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys,

I solved my problem by using tabContol with a hidden headers.

I think it is the best possible solution.